# Color of inactive checkbox in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I created a new theme with the query theme roller.  However, I can't seem to figure out how it is setting the checkbox color when it is not selected.

[image: Unselected]

If you look closely you can see that the box is there with a slightly darker color.  The theme roller or JQM itself, seems to create a darker or lighter shade than the main area.  I've tried searching for that color in the downloaded theme, looked at the applied styles, etc but I can't figure out how this gets set or how I can change it to be either a little darker or a little lighter.

Here is the theme roller link if you want to download the them for yourself:
http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/?ver=1.4.2&style_id=20140322-33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the following it should fix your issue:

```
.ui-btn.ui-checkbox-off:after{
    background:#fff;
    opacity:1;
}
```

By default the opacity was was on:

```
.ui-checkbox-off:after, .ui-btn.ui-radio-off:after
```

And the color was set on:

```
.ui-btn-icon-left:after, .ui-btn-icon-right:after, .ui-btn-icon-top:after, .ui-btn-icon-bottom:after, .ui-btn-icon-notext:after
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect!!  Mind if I ask how you found that so fast?  Are you just that familiar with JQM, or did you debug/inspect the result and work backwards.  If the latter, would you mind telling me what browser/add-ins you use to debug.  IE/F12 came up short for me on this one.

Comment: Just went tot he inspector and scrolled down to see what properties the unchecked box was inheriting. I noticed there was an opacity and a color set. Here's a screencap of how I did it: http://imageshack.com/a/img713/852/qv8p.gif

Comment: Chrome is the difference - IE doesn't show the "::after" element.  Thank you much.  Love the screen capture as an animated gif as well.